# How to pick random image from directory (Using Repl.it)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm making a banana machine and it grabs a random banana image in a directory i created inside the fun directory heres my code:

```js
var fs = require('fs');
  fs.readdir('./fun/bananas/', (err, files) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);

    let bonannapics = files.filter(f => f.split('.').pop() === 'png');

    let chosenFile = bonannapics[Math.floor(Math.random() * bonannapics.length)]
    const attachment = new MessageAttachment(chosenFile)
    let bananaembed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("Bonana Machine")
      .setColor(config.color)
      .setDescription("here is your banana!")
      .attachFiles(attachment)
      .setImage(attachment)
      .setFooter(config.footer)
    message.channel.send(bananaembed);
  });
```

Heres the error:

```js
(node:6072) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/runner/Gloozzys-Treehouse/banana3.png'
```

heres the folder structure:
[folderstructure picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRtGF.png)

it thinks the image is in a different directory but I don't know why, if anyone could help me solve this that would be great.

Comment: Can you update your question and add your folder structure?

Comment: You are reading dir './fun/bananas/' but the image path does not include it, you should check this first,

Comment: @BrunoPigatto Added image

Comment: @HoangHieu I'm trying to make it pick a single image out of the images that are already there

Comment: @Gloozzy `bonana.js` is inside "fun", right? So the path has to start from the location of the current script. Try `./bananas/`

Comment: @BrunoPigatto Ive tried that but it gives the error:
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir './bananas/'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: './bananas/'
}
/home/runner/Gloozzys-Treehouse/fun/bonana.js:15
    let bonannapics = files.filter(f => f.split('.').pop() === 'png');
                            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
    at /home/runner/Gloozzys-Treehouse/fun/bonana.js:15:29

Comment: Try to update this line: 
const attachment = new MessageAttachment(chosenFile)

=> const attachment = new MessageAttachment('./fun/bananas/' + chosenFile)

Answer (score 1):

This line return the list of file in the folder **./fun/bananas/**

```
  fs.readdir('./fun/bananas/', (err, files) => {
```

Reading the file from that folder you have to add the folder path to the MessageAttahment

```
const attachment  = new MessageAttachment(chosenFile)
```

Convert to this.

```
const attachment = new MessageAttachment('./fun/bananas/' + chosenFile)
```